# Yii2 ActiveRecord DB ignores the condition

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

faced with a problem in the database have a column NagrNomer table, and when creating the write controller should check and, if it finds a record he should not add an entry.

```
$model = new FormUnosh(); 

if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
{ 
$sql = 'SELECT NagrNomer FROM FormUnosh';
$provg = FormUnosh::findBySql($sql)->all(); 
foreach ($provg as $item)
{ 
if ($model->NagrNomer!=$item)
{
$model->save(); 
}
return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
else { 
throw new NotFoundHttpException('Not true!'); 
}
}
```

Comment: if ($model->NagrNomer!=$provg) replace with
if ($model->NagrNomer!=$item)

Comment: still goes, I do not even know where the problem is.

Comment: print the $provg = FormUnosh::findBySql($sql)->all(); array and check what are your getting

Comment: try `$item` as `$item[0]`

Comment: either print `$provg` array and show us what you get or try `if ($model->NagrNomer!=$item[0])
{`

Comment: I tried if ($ model-> NagrNomer! = $ item [0]) received Getting unkown property: app\models\FormUnosh::0

Comment: if use the where the design?

Comment: Can you try $item->NagrNomer as foreach is iterating objects. If you still don't get this then use print_r($item); exit(); and paste the result here. We can investigate further.